How to keep a specific expression unevaluated?
For example, I define some quantities here
$$
\gamma=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{c^2 t^2}}},  \qquad \mbox{with} \;  r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2.
$$
Now I want to calculate some expressions. Let's say, $\partial_t \gamma$. So input D[\[Gamma], t] and then output
$$
-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{c^2t^3\left(1-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{c^2 t^2}\right)^\frac32}
$$
The result is clunky. I want it to be neat as
$$
-\frac{r^2\gamma^3}{c^2t^3}
$$
Can you create some function F[#]& such that F[D[\Gamma,t]] will output
$$
-\frac{r^2\gamma^3}{c^2t^3}
$$
where $\gamma$ and $r$ in the output will not be evaluated in terms of $x,y,z,t$?
---------Code-------------
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
\[Gamma] = 1/Sqrt[1 - r^2/(c^2*t^2)]; 
D[\[Gamma], t]
D[\[Gamma], x]
FullSimplify[D[t/\[Gamma], t]]


Please edit the question and include your Mathematica code for the expressions.

For the example in the update, the target expression to aim at is something like HoldForm[D[x*y^3, x]]/(c^3 t^3).  That seems quite different from the goal in the original. Somehow I don't understand when D[] should be evaluated and then transformed back in terms of $\gamma$ and when evaluation should be held.


The question will be reopened once the corresponding code text is added. 2. This is a problem about [tag:semantic-matching], you'll find some examples under the new-added tag.


It's been said already, but since you've updated the question....People here generally like users to post code as copyable Mathematica code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site, helpful

I think of the problem of obtaining a desired algebraic form as a simplifying-expressions problem. In Mathematica, simplification is a discrete global minimization problem. It is rare that obtaining a desired form is a general problem; rather, it depends on specific initial output, the desired output, and the transformation steps it takes to get from one to the other. One might try to come up with a general code that might achieve what the human being has in mind, but given "some expressions," one approach might work for one expression and not another. The simplification returns an expression that has minimal complexity among all the expressions that are a few transformation steps away. The set of transformation steps is finite and not all-encompassing. Sometimes it is easier to type a result by hand than to get Mathematica to compute it for you.

Define what you mean by simpler via ComplexityFunction. The higher the value it returns, the greater the complexity of the expression. Most, including the default Automatic one, are based on LeafCount[], with adjustments.
Define what transformations you want Simplify[] to try via TransformationFunctions. The setting TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, <new funcs>} will add your new funcs. to the standard transformations. Omit Automatic if you want to limit (Full)Simplify to just yours.

The following code attempts to be semi-general. Some of the code is unnecessary for the specific example in the OP.
Block[{\[Gamma], r, c, x, y, z, t, assumptions, relations, 
  differentialrelations, transformations
  , gammapenalty = 15},
 (* ASSUMPTIONS AND RELATIONS *)
 (*   assume c is constant and other variable depend on t *)
 SetAttributes[c, Constant];
 r /: Dt[r, t] = 0;
 (*   assume everything is positive; maybe unnecessary *)
 assumptions = Join[
   Thread[{\[Gamma], r, c, x, y, z, t} > 0],(* maybe? *)
   {1 - r^2/(c^2 t^2) > 0}
   ];
 (*   algebraic relations in polynomial/rational form *)
 relations = { 
   r^2 == x^2 + y^2 + z^2,
   \[Gamma]^2 == 1/(1 - r^2/(c^2*t^2))
   };
 (*   differential relations in terms of Dt[] *)
 differentialrelations = Cases[relations, r_Equal :> Dt[r, t]];
 (* PARTICULAR TRANSFORMATIONS *)
 (*   all variables appear as u^2 so generate replacements for them *)
 transformations = Union[#, Reverse /@ #] &@Flatten[
    Outer[
     Activate[
       Unevaluated@Solve[#, #2, InverseFunctions -> True] /. 
        Power -> Inactive[Power]] &,
     relations, {\[Gamma], r, c, x, y, z}^2],
    3];
 (* SIMPLIFICATION OF DERIVATIVE *)
 Simplify[
  Dt[\[Gamma], t] /. 
   First@Solve[differentialrelations, Dt[\[Gamma], t], {Dt[x, t]}],
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
      gammapenalty*Count[#, \[Gamma], Infinity] &),
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
    Sequence @@ (Function[r, Simplify[# /. r, assumptions] &] /@ 
       transformations)}]
 ]

(*  -((r^2 \[Gamma]^3)/(c^2 t^3))  *)

One of the interesting things about the approach above is the necessity of gammapenalty. If you set gammapenalty = 0 (my original test was without a custom ComplexityFunction), you get the following result, which I thought was better than the one the OP desired:
(*  (\[Gamma] - \[Gamma]^3)/t  *)

What's interesting about it?:

$\partial_t\gamma$ does not depend on $r$ or $c$.
$\gamma$ satisfies a separable ODE $${d\gamma \over dt} = \frac{\gamma -\gamma ^3}{t} \,,$$
in which $r$ and $c$ appear only in the initial conditions. And $\gamma=1$ is a stable equilibrium, but $\gamma=1$ is not attainable in the original formula; possibly something interesting there, if this is a scientific problem.

P.S. I use Echo[] inside Block[] to output steps I want to check.

Using the following rule:
r1 = β -> r^2/(c^2 t^2);

r2 = Expand[First @@ Solve[ApplySides[#^2 &, 
     γ == 1/Sqrt[1 - r^2/(c^2 t^2)]] /. Reverse[r1], β]] /. r1


r^2/(c^2 t^2) -> 1 - 1/γ^2

With[{g = 1/Sqrt[1 - r^2/(c  t)^2]}, PowerExpand[D[g, t] /. r2]] // TeXForm


$-\displaystyle\frac{r^2 \gamma ^3}{c^2 t^3}$


Following your method, I defined a rule def = \[Gamma] -> 1/Sqrt[1 - r^2/(c^2 t^2)] and tried With[{g = \[Gamma] /. def}, PowerExpand[D[g,t] /. Reverse[def]]]. But it doesn't work.

Look at the full form of your derivative:
ex = 1/Sqrt[1 - r^2/(c t)^2];
der = D[ex, t];
der // FullForm


You want to replace the part:
part=Power[Plus[1, Times[-1, Power[c, -2], Power[r, 2], Power[t, -2]]], 
     Rational[-3, 2]]

Therefore:
der /. part -> \[Gamma]^3


